# Regex Match Between

Tags: regex, vb.net, match

I have the following text

```
Ad:<font class=value>1234 Blues  </font>
```

Regex expression

```
value>([^<]+)
```

will match

```
value>1234 Blues
```

What do I need to do for the match to only return

```
1234 Blues
```

using "value>" in the expression (to make the search more specific)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.NET Basic Regex Match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8651771/vb-net-basic-regex-match)

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions here, whether or not you feel your question is being answered quickly enough. You should also not prefix your title with "VB.net", since that's what tags are for.

Comment: I deleted the other one, this one makes more sense.

Comment: Sorry you don't like the answer, but using regex to parse HTML is not the answer.

Comment: It's a conceptual regex question, how to match in between text... that's all I'm asking for John!

Comment: Nonsense. It's not conceptual at all. You want to parse HTML with a regex. Well, you can learn to hang yourself entirely on your own.

Comment: Lol, John, I've considered the alternative of using XPATH as instructed by you, which in any other case I agree would make a lot more sense but it doesn't bring any sort of benefit over using RegEx in this particular case!

Comment: The benefit is that nothing stands still. Your "particular case" next month will be different, especially if this is a web site that doesn't know that it isn't supposed to change its markup.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6178/discussion-between-theveloper-and-john-saunders)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I agree with John Saunders, here is the answer to the question (or at least the one that I could come up with :)

```
<font[^>]*?>(.*?)\s*<\/font>
```

Comment: This matches the whole <font tag and ending </font tag, I just want to retrieve "1234 Blues" after having given regex a specific expression which includes "value>" for it to know where to start. ([^<]+) tells it to end before the first < it encounters.

Comment: I don't know much about VB, but you should get the info from the group, which is the info beetween parentheses. Look for a method to do that. Here is the proof :P http://rubular.com/r/nd8sBtlFxT

Comment: Awesome, I understand now! "Ad:<font[^>]*?value>(.*?)\s*<\/font>" is specific enough to suit my needs. So a Match != a Capture... I think that's where the confusion was.

Comment: Note how fragile that is. All that's necessary to screw it up is to put the attribute values into quotes, or to make the "class" attribute not be the final one, or to change the name of the class, or to add a nested `<font>` element. If this isn't your web page that you're parsing, and if you keep this code for a year, then it _will_ break.

Comment: already removed &nbsp; and quotes from source. I've used split and str.replace until now to parse the same website in the older version of the software I'm developing now for over 4 years, needless to say I had to make minimal changes to it, regex should be a lot more reliable in that respect. I have all my parsing rules in a db and I would simply adjust them from there.